# Upgrade to gpiozero 1.4 on Jessie breaks gpiozero

Tags: raspbian-jessie, gpiozero

On a stock Jessie install, gpiozero works. E.g.

```
>>> from gpiozero.devices import pin_factory
>>> print(pin_factory)
<class 'gpiozero.pins.rpigpio.RPiGPIOPin'>
```

I then upgrade to gpiozero 1.4 with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Which I'd like because the pinout command is super useful, and gpiozero is among the upgrade:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-host debconf debconf-i18n debconf-utils gtk2-engines-pixbuf
  libbind9-90 libc-ares2 libdns-export100 libdns100 libdvdnav4 libgcrypt20
  libgnutls-deb0-28 libgnutls-openssl27 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin
  libgtk2.0-common libirs-export91 libisc-export95 libisc95 libisccc90
  libisccfg-export90 libisccfg90 liblwres90 libsmbclient libtiff5 libwbclient0
  perl perl-base perl-modules python-gpiozero python3-gpiozero python3-thonny
  rpi-chromium-mods samba-common samba-libs xarchiver
```

But although pinout works (it's so cool!) nothing else does, e.g.

```
>>> from gpiozero.devices import pin_factory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name pin_factory
```

And none of my python code with

```
from gpiozero import ...
```

Which used to work does either. For example, for

```
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
ultrasonic = DistanceSensor( echo=17, trigger=4 )
ultrasonic.distance
```

which worked before doesn't. What happens now is that it sits for a while and then outputs 1.0 regardless of what's in front of the HC-SRO4. Any ideas? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us what else _doesn't_ work? There shouldn't be much from the basic functionality that doesn't work - perhaps you're doing something unsupported?

Comment: I updated the question to include an example with the HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor. Thanks!

Comment: Try tweeting @ben_nuttall on Twitter - he helped write it and might know what the prob is.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `gpiozero` shows that the way that you can change the default pin implementation has changed. Before, you changed the variable `gpiozero.devices.pin_factory`; now, you have to specify the `GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY` environment variable when starting Python. For example, instead of doing

```
from gpiozero.pins.native import NativePin
import gpiozero.devices
gpiozero.devices.pin_factory = NativePin
```

you need to start python like this:

```
GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=native python
```

and then `gpiozero.Device.pin_factory` changes to a `NativeFactory` object.

This is all taken from the documentation. Compare the documentation for pins for  [1.4.0](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_pins.html)  and [1.3.2](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/api_pins.html).
The [changelog](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html) should show you all of the other things that now should be done in a different way. Some things seem to have moved. `gpiozero` is **not** broken.

Comment: I looked through the documentation but coming from a mcu world to the pi, I'm still very much green here. Thanks super for your help. I got the pin factory working--at least to tell me about a pin--but what do I need to change in my HC-SR04 code in my updated post to get 1.4 to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Dribbler I’m afraid that I don’t know much at all about gpiozero; I just checked the documentation to get this answer without really knowing much about the subject.